# Getting Date in HTTP format in Java

Tags: java, http, date, time

I'm trying to get a String of a date in Java in the format specified in HTTP 1.1. Which, as far as I can tell, is:

> Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT

With the time always being GMT.

What would be the easiest way to get this from Date/Calendar/?

Comment: @BasilBourque it does not comply if you consider the first 9 days of the month. Rfc 1123 supports 1-2 digits, but http 1.1 requires it to be two digits for the day-of-month.

Comment: @jontejj Thanks For the clarification. I deleted my comments as they were not helpful.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In case someone else will try to find the answer here (like I did) here's what will do the trick:

```
String getServerTime() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    return dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

in order to set the server to speak English and give time in GMT timezone.

Comment: That code is a prime example of why people hate Java.  I went with the answer by @jontejj.

Comment: It should be noted that use of `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe and `dateFormat` must be non-shared or properly synchronized if shared. Better go with Java 8 or Joda Time classes.

Comment: This was a good answer in 2011. It’s just wearing… :-) Certainly agree to look further down the answer list now.

Comment: This Answer is now outdated, using troublesome old date-time classes that were supplanted by the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 78):

## java.time

EDIT:

`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH).withZone(ZoneId.of("GMT"))`

is the way to do it with pure java.time. HTTP 1.1 is to not a 100% match with [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123), so using the java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME formatter will fail for day-of-month less than 10. (thanks to @PavanKamar and @ankon for pointing that out)

Note: to be backwards compliant, you would need to also support the other two formats specified by [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.3.1)

Comment: Lovely to see this in Java 8 but, this didn't quite work for me I had to use ZonedDateTime.now() instead of Instant.now()

Comment: I used this except with ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT")).  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This works only for dates on or after 10th. For single digit dates, RFC 5322 expects the date to be of two digits, but this line of code generates a single digit date field.

http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.3

Comment: @PavanKumar: Good point, but I think the reference is wrong :)

RFC 5322, section 3.3 says `day = ([FWS] 1*2DIGIT FWS) / obs-day`. `1*2DIGIT` means "at least one, at most two of DIGIT" (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5234#section-3.6 as referenced by RFC 5322). 

For the purpose of HTTP/1.1 though: RFC 2616, section 3.3., references a "fixed-length" format of RFC 1123 (which uses the same definition `1*2DIGIT`), defining day as `2DIGIT`. It's a mess :)

Comment: Java 8 Time should be thread safe, unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Yes, these older date-time specs are a mess. Modern protocols adopt the sensible [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Both the java.time and Joda-Time frameworks use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values.

Comment: @jontejj You could replace that `ZoneId.of("GMT")` with the predefined constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`.

Comment: Can also be used in Java 6 & 7 and Android. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

Comment: Please don't vote this up, as @PavanKumar pointed out, it only works for dates on of after the 10th. It took me a day to figure out why my HTTP request fails with a date header generated with this line of code.

Comment: @apcuk date formats referenced from older http rfcs should still be supported/accepted. So I would assume that the parser you have doesn't? "HTTP/1.1 clients and servers that parse the date value MUST accept all three formats (for compatibility with HTTP/1.0), though they MUST only generate the RFC 1123 format for representing HTTP-date values in header fields." - from the http rfc.

Comment: @jontejj I was trying to connect to Azure, and it said that it uses RFC1123 as date format. I was happy to find it as a built-in pattern in Java 8. But it only accepted my header with a fixed-length day-of-month, and it was extremely hard to figure out what was wrong... It's not completely clear to me, but it seems that the HTTP standard is a "subset" of RFC1123, so I think your answer is fine if you need RFC1123, but not for all HTTP requests.

Comment: Not according to the quote I found? I think that either java 8 or azure has a bug? I need to dig deeper into the format to be sure, will get back to you on that.

Comment: Gili thanks for reminding me :) @apcuk it seems like you are correct... [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51636514/541755](@malt's answer) is the better answer. HTTP 1/1 indeed uses a modified rfc1123 format. So the sad news is that there is no built in formatter in java 8 for parsing/formatting http dates...

Comment: *Beware of locale* This format, while correct, is locale-dependent. You must use an English locale for generating compliant HTTP dates.

Comment: @EtienneMiret I edited the answer to account for that.

Comment: @BasilBourque if you use ZoneOffset.UTC it prints Z instead of GMT

Comment: @jontejj Yes, indeed, you are right about that `Z`appearing  instead `GMT`. Surprised me. See [demo in IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/B9MZEM). FYI, semantically, they mean the same, `Z` & `GMT` being an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Answer (score 27):

If you're using [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) (which I would highly recommend for any handling of dates and times in Java), you can do:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

...

private static final DateTimeFormatter RFC1123_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = 
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'")
    .withZoneUTC().withLocale(Locale.US);

...

RFC1123_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.print(new DateTime())
```

Comment: This worked great. However, to ensure an English locale I had to add: `private static final DateTimeFormatter RFC1123_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'").withZoneUTC().withLocale(Locale.US);`

Comment: The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: I was looking for a way to print the `String`  "UTC" to a `java.time.DateTimeFormatter` and found your answer useful!

Answer (score 18):

## Two-digit day-of-month

Some applications require the format to include a two digit day-of-month as per [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1). The Java 8 `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` uses a single digit:

```
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.format(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)));
```

Output: `Wed, 1 Aug 2018 14:56:46 GMT`

Some applications don't like that. Before you use the old answers that use Joda-time or a pre-java8 `SimpleDateFormat`, here's a working Java-8 `DateTimeFormatter`:

`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss O")`

Now, when you do this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss O");
System.out.println(formatter.format(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)));
```

You get `Wed, 01 Aug 2018 14:56:46 GMT` - note the leading zero in the day-of-month field.

Comment: You need to remember also to set the English locale in the formatter

Comment: @JacekObarymski How would I do that? `withLocale(Locale.US)` gives the same result.

Comment: @pjanssen DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss O", Locale.ENGLISH).
If your default locale is English then you might not see the difference but it's still a good practice IMHO.

Comment: @JacekObarymski Ah, I thought you meant setting the locale on `RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` would add the leading zero.

Comment: No, what I mean is that if you use that pattern "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss O" and don't have English locale set then the abbreviated month name 'MMM' will be in you locale's language which obviously won't be RFC_1123 compliant anymore

Answer (score 11):

If you, like me, are trying to format a Java 8 `java.time.Instant` you need to explicitly add the time zone to the formatter. Like this:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
String formatted = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME
        .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
        .format(instant);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Which prints:

> Tue, 15 Mar 2016 14:45:34 GMT

Comment: Good answer. Alternative syntax: `OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).format( DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME )`

Comment: When GMT offset is a requirement for the formatting, I certainly like the idea of making the offset an attribute of the formatter. Immediately upvoted.

Answer (score 8):

If you are not afraid of additional dependencies, you can use apache DateUtils:

```
import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils;
DateUtils.formatDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
// Tue, 17 Apr 2012 18:59:02 GMT
```

This will format your date with respect to <s>[RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822)</s> [RFC1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123).

Comment: RFC 822 actually states a 2 digit year, however, [RFC 1123](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1123) which supersedes RFC 822 changes this to a 4 digit year.

Comment: Looks like `org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils` is deprecated. The `formatDate` method now lives in `org.apache.http.client.utils.DateUtils`.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a late response but just wanted to add it for completeness.

You did not mention what you need the string for. But if you need it for an HTTP response header, you can use HttpServletResponse.setDateHeader(). It does all the formatting for you.

Comment: [Link to doc: `HttpServletResponse.setDateHeader()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setDateHeader-java.lang.String-long-). It accpets millis since the epoch. You can for instance get those from `Instant.toEpochMilli()` or (old-fashioned) `Date.getTime()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
System.out.println("Date: " + dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

You can play with it. The documentation is here: 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: What about the requirement that it be in GMT?

Comment: I also think the above example returns the date in system timezone, not GMT (of course it works if you set system timezone to GMT in the Locale, but not everybody are willing to do that) so - anyone - what would be the complete answer?