# Scala: How do I get the current time in RFC 822 / 1123 format

Tags: scala, time

How do I get the current time GMT date-time in [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) / [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) format in Scala, to put into an HTTP header? Preferably using the built in Java 8 classes.

For some reason what I thought would be a simple generic task has eluded me.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284775/how-do-i-parse-and-convert-datetime-s-to-the-rfc-822-date-time-format

Comment: Or see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26367834/151004

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to get the current date time and [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to format it using its existing formatter for RFC 822 / 1123: [`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)

```
import java.time.{ZonedDateTime, ZoneOffset}
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val datetime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME

datetime.format(formatter)
// String = Wed, 16 Sep 2015 21:45:10 GMT
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Peter Neyens for this answer which I've converted into a method, as I wanted as succinct as possible paste in code.

```
import java.time._ 
def nowHttp: String = "Date: " +
  ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(format.DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)
```

I've left off the "\r\n" for consistency as I use a specially defined operator to terminate and add an HTTP header line.