# Convert date to EEE, d MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss z format

Tags: java, date

I want to format date to string in "EEE, d MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss z" but not able to receive desired output.

I referred this [tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Format/0030__Java_Date_Format_Symbol.htm)  however it not working as per expectation , see code below :

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss z");
        //tried this as well  new SimpleDateFormat("EEE',' d MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss z",Locale.US);
        String strDate = date.toString();
        System.out.println(strDate);// Tue Sep 19 10:31:40 GMT 2017
        // i want this --> Tue, Sep 19 2017 10:31:40 GMT 

    }
}
```

Please find [jdoodle link](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/7A8) for working example 
Appreciate your help !

Comment: And why do you expect to get the correct format when you don't even use the formatter?

Comment: I realise the mistake i made , i am fairly new to java , thanks for your responses.

Comment: You should try to use an IDE like Netbeans, Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA. They would tell you that `formatter` is currently unused and make it easier to detect such issues in an instant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Date in HTTP format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707555/getting-date-in-http-format-in-java). That question is specifically about the same format. The format is also known as RFC 1123 or HTTP format.

Comment: I always recommend throwing out the long outdated classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` and using the modern Java date and time API instead. I do particularly in this case since the modern API includes a built-in formatter that gives you exactly what you want: [`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME). There’s more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26367834/5772882).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a DateFormat, but the you didn't use it. Change

```
String strDate = date.toString();
```

to

```
String strDate = formatter.format(date);
```

Comment: **Tom marked as duplicate** , **Leo** Thanks +1 :)

Comment: @Tom did not know the question was a duplicate. My bad.