# How to convert Gmail date format to java.util.Date?

Tags: java, talend

I try to retrieve mails from a Gmail account using tPOP and then save somewhere the date of the last mail retrieved (so the next time I run the job I won't be retrieving the same mails twice).

The only date that I could retrieve from a gmail mail got this format :

> Fri, 13 Apr 2018 02:26:19 -0700 (PDT)

How can I convert this into a Java.util.Date format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion). And of many more questions, please search.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are asking for `java.util.Date`? That class is considered long outmoded. Instead I recommend you go for [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: FYI, as Ole V.V. commented, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
String input = "Fri, 13 Apr 2018 02:26:19 -0700 (PDT)" ;
…
java.util.Date.from(                                     // Convert from modern classes `OffsetDateTime` & `Instant` to troublesome legacy class `Date`. Do so only if absolutely necessary.
    OffsetDateTime.parse(
        input.substring( 0 , input.indexOf( " (" ) ) ,   // Drop the ambiguity-prone pseudo-zone ` (PDT)` from the end.
        DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME             // Parse using a built-in formatter defined for RFC 1123 strings.
    )
    .toInstant()                                         // Extract UTC value (`Instant`) from `OffsetDateTime`.
)                                                        // Returns a legacy `java.util.Date` object.
```

## `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`

As discussed in [the Answer by GPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49815470/642706), Java provides a formatter for this format defined in RFC 1123 (see also RFC 822).

Except that pseudo-time-zone codes such as `PDT` cannot be parsed unambiguously as they are not standardized and are not unique. So strip that off.

```
String original = "Fri, 13 Apr 2018 02:26:19 -0700 (PDT)";
// Delete non-standard pseudo-zone at end.
String input = original;
if ( input.endsWith( ")" ) ) {
    int index = input.indexOf( " (" );
    input = input.substring( 0 , index );
}
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( original );
System.out.println( input );
System.out.println( odt );
```

> Fri, 13 Apr 2018 02:26:19 -0700 (PDT)
>
> Fri, 13 Apr 2018 02:26:19 -0700
>
> 2018-04-13T02:26:19-07:00

## Convert

> How can I convert this into a Java.util.Date format?

Don’t. The `java.util.Date` is a poorly-designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid it.

But if you must interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time* classes, you can convert back and forth. Call new methods added to the old classes.

Extract a `Instant` from `OffsetDateTime`, as that class replaces `java.util.Date` to represent a moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: While your hack works, two erroraneous statements should be corrected: a) The input string is not defined in RFC 1123 but RFC 5322 which allows comments (the trailing "(PDT)" is indeed such a comment). b) In RFC 1123, the zones PDT etc. are NOT ambigous but well defined and exclusively related to North America, see the original paper in [RFC 822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt) - page 25).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for this task:

```
String dt = "Fri, 13 Apr 2018 02:26:19 -0700 (PDT)";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dt);
```

Read more:

- [`DateFormat::parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but It gives me this error : `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri, 13 Apr 2018 02:26:19 -0700 (PDT)"`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat : simple date formats are locale sensitive. "Fri" has a meaning in english, not in french or russian or whatever. Therefore, a "french" SimpleDateFormat will fail to parse it. You should probably set the SimpleDateFormat's locale before parsing . Anyway, this is not a complete answer (although it should work most of the time). See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17404726/2131074 : day of week is optional and timezone specification are not taken into account in this sample, both of which may lead to a parsing failure.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I still have the same issue after adding the Locale.ENGLISH.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: java.time is not available to Android API <26

Sucks, but this answer is still pretty valuable

Answer (score 1):

Other answers to date, although they will probably work most of the time, do not take into account the subtelties of the [RFC1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-55) format (see section 5.2.14, that replaces the original [RFC-822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5) definition).

By this normative definition, the day of week field is optional (`SimpleDateForamt` can not deal with optional fields), and the timezones may be provided both as +/- offsets (capital Z in SimpleDateFormat), or as names (lowercase z in SimpleDateFormat).

You could create a combination of SimpleDateFormats, and see which match, but that is slow. You could use `JodaTime` and build the optional parts because it has an API for that, but that takes time too.

Or if you have Java8+, you have `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` for free. Which is not a complete implementation of the standard, but probably as close as you will ever get if you code it yourself. And probably safer too.

See also : [Getting Date in HTTP format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707555/getting-date-in-http-format-in-java)

Comment: `RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` won't take into account the time-zone name, I don't think.

Comment: It says it does. Javadoc : `The format consists of: [...] The {@link ZoneOffset#getId() offset ID} without colons or seconds. An offset of zero uses "GMT. `, although as a matter of text recognition of timezones, only GMT is recognized, not the normative possibilities of various american timezones. In the question's case, the GMT based numerical offset is used, not such a text timezone.

Answer (score 1):

## Use `Message-ID:` header instead

> the next time I run the job I won't be retrieving the same mails twice

To avoid downloading the same message, use the `Message-ID:` header rather than the `Date:`. That is its purpose, to identify each message uniquely. No need to parse anything.

See [fields described here](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Gmail_Header_Format).

Example:

```
Message-ID: <f6a363400703050910y7d591d42raf015fcef16f95ea@mail.gmail.com>
Date: Mon, 5 Mar 2007 09:10:41 -0800
From: UserName <address@gmail.com>
To: OtherUserName <address@system.com>
Subject: Subject Line
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Use this string as your unique identifier:

> f6a363400703050910y7d591d42raf015fcef16f95ea@mail.gmail.com